# Amazon SNS with java, Send group SMS to all over the world

Tags: java, sms, amazon-sns, bulksms

I am trying to integrate send promotional SMS messages to customers. For this can I use amazon SNS, and can I integrate this SNS with my web application?

I am using java and I want send group SMS with one click in my web application.

Also, is there any better solution rather than Amazon SNS?

Comment: i am also searching for a better option

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SNS can send messages via **SMS**. Sending options are:

- Send a message to a **single recipient**, or
- Subscribe **multiple recipients** to an SNS topic, then send the message to the SNS topic. All subscribers will receive the message.

If you wish to send a **different message to each recipient**, use the first option. If you are regularly sending a message to the **same group of recipients**, use the second option. However, if the group of recipients frequently changes, it may be easiest to send each message individually.

See documentation: [Sending SMS Messages with Amazon SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SMSMessages.html)

Comment: I read that documentation, but in that there is no idea how to implement to in web application,